# How to write select query for multiple column in a room database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to get filtered record base on multiple columns("race","flavors").

You can see below image of database where red box is item_type and blue box where you can see item_flavors. [image]

Now I wanted to get all "sativa" (item_type) with all of this "Citrus","Berry","Nutty"(item_flavors). And for this I wrote this query.

```
SELECT * FROM StrainModel WHERE race LIKE 'sativa' AND flavors LIKE '%Berry%' OR flavors LIKE '%Citrus%' OR flavors LIKE '%Nutty%'
```

But this query was wrong and give me all three type of data("sativa","indica","hybrid"), but I just wanted "sativa" data.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM StrainModel WHERE race = 'sativa' AND (flavors LIKE '%Berry%' OR flavors LIKE '%Citrus%' OR flavors LIKE '%Nutty%')`

Comment: its working dude.... Thank you

Comment: @PrashantArvind you can use stetho to view the database in the browser. It will save time for debugging http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
SELECT * FROM StrainModel WHERE race = 'sativa' AND (flavors LIKE '%Berry%' OR flavors LIKE '%Citrus%' OR flavors LIKE '%Nutty%')
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM StrainModel WHERE race LIKE 'sativa' AND flavors LIKE '%Berry%' OR flavors LIKE '%Citrus%' OR flavors LIKE '%Nutty%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM StrainModel WHERE (race = 'sativa' AND (flavors LIKE '%Berry%' OR flavors LIKE '%Citrus%' OR flavors LIKE '%Nutty%'));
```